# Adding a new backend in Python Social Auth

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

The docs for python-social auth describe how to add an authentication backend, but the don't say where to put the `CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET` of the new backed.

Here are the docs in question: http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/implementation.html#oauth

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented it this way:

```
from django.conf import settings

class CustomOAuth2(BaseOAuth2):
    name = 'custom'

    def get_key_and_secret(self):
        return settings.CUSTOM_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID, settings.CUSTOM_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET
```

Comment: While this works, it's not the best approach.  Python-socail-auth has support for Django settings, and these are auto-generated for any custom backend.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65891608/2800876 for how to set them

Answer (score 2):

You specify them as django settings.  The name of the settings are dynamically generated based on the `name` parameter of your custom backend, and are of the format `SOCAIL_AUTH_[BACKEND_NAME]_KEY` and `SOCAIL_AUTH_[BACKEND_NAME]_SECRET`.

So, for example, if your custom backend looks like this:

```
class TimelyOAuth2(BaseOAuth2):
    name = "custom-backend"
    # ...
```

You would put the following in settings.py:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_CUSTOM_BACKEND_KEY = "..."
SOCIAL_AUTH_CUSTOM_BACKEND_SECRET = "..."
```

(Of course, don't put your key and secret directly in settings; use something like [Django-environ](https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/))

---

## Source

This is not documented anywhere in python-social-auth that I can find.  I found this by reading the relevant bits of code in social_core/backends/base.py, social_core/strategy.py, and social_core/utils.py.  The key method is `get_key_and_secret` which attempts to source these from settings variables.  Relevant code excerpts are below:

```
# social_core/backends/base.py
class BaseAuth(object):
    def get_key_and_secret(self):
         return self.setting('KEY'), self.setting('SECRET')


# social_core/strategy.py
class BaseStrategy(object):
    def setting(self, name, default=None, backend=None):
        names = [setting_name(name), name]
        if backend:
            names.insert(0, setting_name(backend.name, name))
        for name in names:
            try:
                return self.get_setting(name)
            except (AttributeError, KeyError):
                pass
        return default


# social_core/utils.py
SETTING_PREFIX = 'SOCIAL_AUTH'

def to_setting_name(*names):
    return '_'.join([name.upper().replace('-', '_') for name in names if name])

def setting_name(*names):
    return to_setting_name(*((SETTING_PREFIX,) + names))
```